# Handle CORS HTTP Options Preflight Request in a .NET 6 Minimal API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

Can't seem to figure out how to handle a CORS Options (preflight) request in a minimal API in .NET 6.

While there is a MapGet and MapPost for routing, there is not a MapOptions specifically. We do have MapMethods, which I have attempted to use to force a 200 response to an options request as shown below, but this seems to break Swagger:

```
app.MapGet("/HelloWorld", () => "Hello World!"); 
app.MapMethods("/HelloWorld", new[] {"OPTIONS", "HEAD"},
            () => processOptions);
app.Run();
IResult processOptions()
{
    return Results.Ok();
}
```

The documentation mentions doing it in a controller based API as shown below, but I'm not sure how to translate this to a minimal api

In .NET Framework 4.7, I would add the following which would allow a 200 ok response to options requests:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

(The comments inside the Response.End method say it did the following):

```
 // Summary:
    //     Sends all currently buffered output to the client, stops execution of the page,
    //     and raises the System.Web.HttpApplication.EndRequest event.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.Threading.ThreadAbortException:
    //     The call to System.Web.HttpResponse.End has terminated the current request
```

The use of the Application_AuthenticateRequest to get the Options request to work in .Net Framework 4.7 also leads me to think maybe what is happening is I somehow need to authenticate the user, and it's not a CORS option problem at all which is a separate question..

This question: what is the proper way to handle options requests in .NET 6+?

Comment: `OPTIONS` preflight requests do NOT send any cookies, so you can't log people in.

Comment: What might cause a preflight to get a 401 unauthorized then?

Comment: That's exactly because the user is NOT logged in.

Comment: Gotcha. But how would a user ever log in from another domain if the preflight options request is going to block them from doing so?

Comment: You should search for: `Service.AddCors` and `app.UseCors()` to set up cors in asp.net.

Comment: `UseCors` must run BEFORE authentication to avoid that probelm.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could write a custom middleware to achieve your requirement.

If you want to match the option and head request and return someting inside your application, you could write below middleware and put it at the begin of your application.

Then all the option and head request will return the 200 to the client.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var methodvalue = context.Request.Method;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodvalue))
    {
 
        if (methodvalue == HttpMethods.Options || methodvalue == HttpMethods.Head)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Option Request");
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    }
});
```

Result:

[image]